# Change the color of Contextual Action Bar

Tags: android, fragment, cab

I'm trying to figure out how to change the color of the contextual action bar menu (CAB)
for example i want to have red CAB in my app,and i use the CAB in one of my fragments,
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add following in your theme defined under `styles.xml`,​

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
<item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/actionmode_background</item>`
```

Answer (score 1):

create a new style like below and use that style in your activity theme

```
<style name="styleActionMode" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
<item name="background">your color code</item>
<item name="actionMenuTextColor">your color code</item>
```